How to extract land cover type for specific sites from QGIS?
I have the Ontario Land Cover layer in QGIS (I used the OLCC_V2_TIFF layer into QGIS) and I have my CSV with site coordinates overlayed.
I am wondering now how to actually extract the land cover data for each of my sites within a 500m radius around each one. I am not sure how to get QGIS to add a 500m radius/buffer around my points and then from that, whatever land cover (pixels) are in that radius, extract that info so I can obtain a clear understanding of land type.
Ideally, I would end up with something like SiteA has 33% forest cover, 12.1% water, 55% impervious cover, etc.

More details on what you'd like to do, and one question per post please.

Updated - added more details to clarify.

Your question is likely to get closed because it violates the GIS SE rules for one focused question and one answer model.  Please take the tour.
Here are the steps to get you started.  If you have a question or problem with any one of these steps you should post a new and focused question on that particular problem.
Here is a tutorial on buffering. Buffer your points by your required distance. Take those buffers and use the zonal histogram tool available in the processing toolbox using your land cover data.  After running the zonal histogram tool you will see some new attributes in the attribute table. These histogram values are the pixel counts for each pixel type. You can look up the pixel size of your land cover data and calculate the area of those pixel by type thus getting your percentages.
Here is a screen shot of the zonal histogram output in the resulting output from zonal histogram.  I have 1 pixel of value 2, 19 pixels of value 4, 386 pixels of value 6...


So I ran and I got my values for each buffer site but it seems like the values are off....One site was coming up with 100% of the pixels matching to category of Community/Infrastructure but on the map itself it should be under forest cover. And actually when zooming into the site with its buffer on in the raster map, there should be many more HISTO_# with values but only one of them came up with a count of pixels. It seems like it did not actually do it for the buffer zone.

Nevermind it is correct, it could just be an issue with the latest file I'm using that doesn't seem to match another map that has more land cover types in it. But this worked so thank you very much!

Somewhat cumbersome if you have many different raster values but it works:

Buffer the points with 500 m
Zonal histogram with the raster as "Raster layer" and Buffer


The output will be a copy of the input layer with an additional column for each overlapping raster value, where the value is the number of pixels with that raster value:

Use the layer as input to Refactor fields, load fields from the layer:

Modify all the source expressions to calculate the percentage of that raster value (use copy paste). Change the output names and data type to decimal.

Result:

